# Number of new lines from joining all intersections of non parallel, non concurrent n straight lines

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

no 3 lines are parallel, no 3 lines are concurrent.

Number of intersections : ${n \choose 2} = x$

From my perspective, answer should be ${x \choose 2} - n\cdot {n \choose 2}$
I just removed the lines formed from joining of the intersections which coincide with the orginal lines since n lines had n points each on them.

Assumimg no 3 intersections are collinear except the ones on a particular original line.

Answer in book, when converted to my form, is
${x \choose 2} - (n-2)\cdot {n \choose 2}$.

EDIT : My Mistake : There are n-1 points on each line.
(sorry, had sleep deprivation..)

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: two lines can be parallels? That is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said before, there are $x={n \choose 2}$ intersections of the lines as long as no two are parallel and not three meet at a point.  Each line has $n-1$ points on it, so there are ${n-1 \choose 2}$ pairs that give that existing line.  The number of new lines is then ${x\choose 2}-n{n-1 \choose 2}$  We can rework the last term as $n{n-1 \choose 2}=\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}2=(n-2){n \choose 2}$ so the final number becomes $${x\choose 2}-(n-2){n \choose 2}=\frac 18(n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n)$$

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake in the statement. In order to get the expected answer two lines can't be parallels (and not three lines like is said).

If there is no parallel lines and there is no three lines go through the same point then the number of intersections is:

$$x={n \choose 2}$$

If we have $n$ line, each one has $n-1$ points on it what give us $n-2$ segments on the same line and we have to take off all those segments.

We might to think that we have to consider $[n(n-1)](n-2)$ segments to be discounted but we have to remmember that all $n(n-1)$ points have been counted twice because each one belongs to two lines so in fact we have to discount:

$$(n-2)\left[\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right]=(n-2){n \choose 2}$$

Then the number of segments connecting those points that are not given by the original lines are:

$${x \choose 2}-(n-2)\cdot {n \choose 2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the $n$ lines are in "general position", so that no two lines are parallel, in addition to the conditions stated in the question.

Note that any $4$ of the old lines will determine $3$ new lines. Namely, if we call the lines $A,B,C,D$ and write $XY$ for the intersection point of the lines $X$ and $Y,$ then each of the pairs $AB$ & $CD,\ $$AC$ & $BD,\ $$AD$ & $BC$ determines a new line. Every new line is obtained (without repetitions) from a quadruple of old lines in this way. Thus the number of new lines is
$$3\binom n4=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}8=\frac{n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n}8$$
which agrees with the other answers, but I think
$$3\binom n4$$
is a prettier way to write it than
$$\binom{\binom n2}2-(n-2)\binom n2.$$